# How to append image src using option tag with datalist tag?

Tags: jquery, html

Actually I want to append product name with image thumbnail. I have done appending product name in datalist tag but image src is not appending Please anyone help me,

Below is my code,

```
<div id="search" class="input-group">
  <input type="text" id="search_suggest" name="search" list="products" value="<?php echo $search; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $text_search; ?>" class="form-control input-lg" />
  <datalist id="products">
  </datalist>
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
  </span>
</div>
```

Js,

```
$(document).on('keyup','#search_suggest',function(){
  var product_name    = $(this).val();
  var x = 'image/no_image.png';
    $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=product/search/search_suggestion',
            type: 'post',
            data: {'search': product_name},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) { 
            // console.log(response);
            var data = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(response));
            // console.log(data);
            $('#products').empty();
            $.each(data, function(i, res){
              $('#products').append('<option value="'+res['name']+'"><img src="'+x+'"/></option>');
              // $('#products').append('<option><img src="'+x+'"/></option>');
              });                                    
          },    
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { 
              alert('error');               ;
              console.log(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);                     
          }
      });
  });
```

Comment: you might need to trim()  the response data - the re always seems to be a whitespace issue on the Ajax return. try :var data = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(response.trim()));

Comment: No its not working.

Answer (score 2):

**img** tag not run in **option** tag it shows null value

create your own drop down using html **div** and **jQuery**

```css
/************** Skin 1 *********************/

.dd {
  /*display:inline-block !important;*/
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  float: left;
}
.dd .ddTitle {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
  padding: 3px;
  text-indent: 0;
  cursor: default;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 16px;
}
.dd .ddTitle span.arrow {
  background: url(dd_arrow.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.dd .ddTitle span.ddTitleText {
  text-indent: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 16px;
}
.dd .ddTitle span.ddTitleText img {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0 2px 0 0
}
.dd .ddTitle img.selected {
  padding: 0 3px 0 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.dd .ddChild {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
  border-top: none;
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  width: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden !important;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.dd .ddChild .opta a,
.dd .ddChild .opta a:visited {
  padding-left: 10px
}
.dd .ddChild a {
  display: block;
  padding: 2px 0 2px 3px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.dd .ddChild a:hover {
  background-color: #66CCFF;
}
.dd .ddChild a img {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0 2px 0 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.dd .ddChild a.selected {
  background-color: #66CCFF;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.dd .borderTop {
  border-top: 1px solid #c3c3c3 !important;
}
.dd .noBorderTop {
  border-top: none 0 !important
}
/************** Skin 2 *********************/

.dd2 {
  /*display:inline-block !important;*/
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  float: left;
}
.dd2 .ddTitle {
  background: transparent url(../images/msDropDown.gif) no-repeat;
  padding: 0 3px;
  text-indent: 0;
  cursor: default;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 36px;
}
.dd2 .ddTitle span.arrow {
  background: transparent url(../images/icon-arrow.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 27px;
  height: 27px;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 5px;
  position: relative;
  right: 2px;
}
.dd2 .ddTitle span.ddTitleText {
  text-indent: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 33px;
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  _position: relative;
  _top: 4px
}
.dd2 .ddTitle span.ddTitleText img {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0 2px 0 0;
}
.dd2 .ddTitle img.selected {
  padding: 0 2px 0 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.dd2 .ddChild {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
  border-top: none;
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  width: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden !important;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.dd2 .ddChild .opta a,
.dd2 .ddChild .opta a:visited {
  padding-left: 10px
}
.dd2 .ddChild a {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 0 3px 3px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.dd2 .ddChild a:hover {
  background-color: #66CCFF;
}
.dd2 .ddChild a img {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0 2px 0 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.dd2 .ddChild a.selected {
  background-color: #66CCFF;
}
.dd2 .borderTop {
  border-top: 1px solid #c3c3c3 !important;
}
.dd2 .noBorderTop {
  border-top: none 0 !important
}
/************* use sprite *****************/

.dd .ddChild a.sprite,
.dd .ddChild a.sprite:visited {
  background-image: url(../icons/sprite.gif);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-left: 24px;
}
.dd .ddChild a.calendar,
.dd .ddChild a.calendar:visited {
  background-position: 0 -404px;
}
.dd .ddChild a.shoppingcart,
.dd .ddChild a.shoppingcart:visited {
  background-position: 0 -330px;
}
.dd .ddChild a.cd,
.dd .ddChild a.cd:visited {
  background-position: 0 -439px;
}
.dd .ddChild a.email,
.dd .ddChild a.email:visited {
  background-position: 0 -256px;
}
.dd .ddChild a.faq,
.dd .ddChild a.faq:visited {
  background-position: 0 -183px;
}
.dd .ddChild a.games,
.dd .ddChild a.games:visited {
  background-position: 0 -365px;
}
.dd .ddChild a.music,
.dd .ddChild a.music:visited {
  background-position: 0 -146px;
}
.dd .ddChild a.phone,
.dd .ddChild a.phone:visited {
  background-position: 0 -109px;
}
.dd .ddChild a.graph,
.dd .ddChild a.graph:visited {
  background-position: 0 -73px;
}
.dd .ddChild a.secured,
.dd .ddChild a.secured:visited {
  background-position: 0 -37px;
}
.dd .ddChild a.video,
.dd .ddChild a.video:visited {
  background-position: 0 0;
}
/*******************************/
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://github.com/USAMA-app/JsFile/blob/master/jquery.dd.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
      try {
        $("body select").msDropDown();
      } catch (e) {
        alert(e.message);
      }
    });


    function showValue(a) {
      console.log(a);
    }
  </script>

</head>

<body>

  <select name="webmenu" id="webmenu" onchange="showValue(this.value)">
    <option value="calendar" title="icons/icon_calendar.gif">Calendar</option>
    <option value="shopping_cart" title="icons/icon_cart.gif">Shopping Cart</option>
    <option value="cd" title="icons/icon_cd.gif">CD</option>
    <option value="email" selected="selected" title="icons/icon_calendar.gif">Email</option>
    <option value="faq" title="icons/icon_faq.gif">FAQ</option>
    <option value="games" title="icons/icon_games.gif">Games</option>
  </select>
</body>
<html>
```

---

or you can **Download** this from here 
https://github.com/USAMA-app/JsFile/blob/master/Drop%20Down%20Picture.rar